# Cookies available in network response header but not available in application storage cookies tab

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, setcookie, httpcookie

I am trying to set a simple cookie using express res.cookies() but the cookies are not being set in the application tab. My frontend is in React and backend is in node. The application work well when I run it on localhost but when I deploy application on "onrender", the cookies are not getting set.

Sharing code for both frontend and backend.

**Server Side:**
**index.ts**

```
const express=require('express')
const app=express()
const mongoose=require('mongoose')
const user_route=require("./routes/users_route")
const cors=require('cors')
const cookieParser=require('cookie-parser')
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors({
    credentials:true,
    origin:"https://surveyfrontend1.onrender.com/",
}))
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use("/users",user_route)

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://testuser:testuser123@cluster0.ynlelsn.mongodb.net/survey-data")
    .then(()=>console.log("Connection to mongoose server successfull"))
    .catch((error)=>console.log("Connection Failed",error))

app.listen(3000,()=>console.log("Backend server running on port 3000...."))
```

**user_router.ts**

```
const express=require('express')
const router=express.Router()
const bcrypt=require('bcrypt')
const {Users,validateUsers}=require("../models/users_models")

router.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.cookie('jwtCookieget',"dummydataaasdasfahsfdf",{
    httpOnly:true,
    maxAge:60*60*3*100000,
    secure: true,
    sameSite:'none',
    
})
    res.send("Get Router")
})

router.post("/",async (req,res)=>{
    const {errors}=validateUsers(req.body)
    if(errors) return res.status(400).send("Something went wrong")

    let user=await Users.findOne({email:req.body.email})
    if(user) return res.status(400).send("User already Registered")

    user=new Users({
        username:req.body.username,
        email:req.body.email,
        password:req.body.password,
    })

    const salt=await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    user.password=await bcrypt.hash(user.password,salt)

    await user.save()

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true"); 
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST"); 
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, *");
    res.cookie('jwtCookie',"dummydataaasdasfahsfdf",{httpOnly:true,maxAge:60*60*3*1000})
    res.send(user)
})

module.exports=router
```

**Frontend:**

```
import React, { FormEvent } from 'react'
import {useForm,SubmitHandler} from "react-hook-form"
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import axios from "axios"


interface Props{
    username:String,
    email:String,
    password:String,
    confirmpass:String
}

const SurveyForm = () => {
    const {register,handleSubmit,formState:{errors},reset} =useForm<Props>()
    

    const handleGet=(e:FormEvent)=>{
      e.preventDefault()
      axios.get("https://backendsurvey.onrender.com/users",{withCredentials:true})
      .then(res=>console.log(res))
      .catch(error=>console.log(error))
    }
    

    const onFormSubmit=async (data:Props)=>{
      console.log(data)
      if(data.password!==data.confirmpass){
        toast("Password do not match")
        return
      }
      
      const response=await fetch("https://backendsurvey.onrender.com/users",{
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
          'Content-Type':'application/json',
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        body:JSON.stringify(data)
      })

      const json=await response.json()
      if(!response.ok){
        console.log("Something went wrong in form submission",json)
      }
      if(response.ok){
        console.log("User created Successfully",json)
        reset()
      }
    }

    const resetForm=(e:FormEvent)=>{
      e.preventDefault()
      reset()
    }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data)=>onFormSubmit(data))}>
        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" className='form-control w-25' id='username' {...register("username",{required:true})} />
        {errors.username && <p className='text-danger'>Field cannot be empty.</p>}
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" className='form-control w-25' id='email' {...register("email", {required:true})} />
        {errors.email && <p className='text-danger'>Field cannot be empty.</p>}
        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" className='form-control w-25' id='password' {...register("password",{required:true})} />
        {errors.password && <p className='text-danger'>Field cannot be empty.</p>}
        <label htmlFor="confirmpass">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="confirmpass" className='form-control w-25' {...register("confirmpass",{required:true})} />
        {errors.confirmpass && <p className='text-danger'>Field cannot be empty.</p>}
        <ToastContainer />
        <button className="btn btn-primary" type='submit'>Submit</button>
        <button className="btn btn-danger m-3" onClick={(e)=>resetForm(e)}>Clear</button>
        <button className="btn btn-danger m-3" onClick={(e)=>handleGet(e)}>Get Cookies</button>
        
    </form>
  )
}

export default SurveyForm
```

Please help I am stuck with this since last 12 hours.

The cookies are not set under the application tab. I tried all the options mentioned in other related posts but nothing is working for me.
Sharing it repo links :
Frontend : https://github.com/vupadhayayx86/simplesurveyfrontend/tree/main
Backend: https://github.com/vupadhayayx86/simple_survey_from_backend/tree/main

Comment: Tried but had no success :(. Here's link to frontend https://surveyfrontend1.onrender.com/

Comment: Could you please upvote my question I need some repo to post comments on other answers. @deepanshu

Comment: I came across the same issue again while working with mysql and Express application and after multiple trials and errors I fixed the issue. Make sure that on the client side while making post request withCredential is set to true and on the server side the cors credential option is set to true. Posting code snippet that worked for me  
//Client Side 
const handleSubmit=(e:any)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/auth/login",logininputs,{withCredentials:true})
    .then((res)=>console.log(res.data))
    .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
  }

Answer (score 0):

So finally after 18 hours, I figured out a solution to this problem. I didn't set the path for the res. cookie() on the server; when I did that, I could see cookies under my application tab.

```
const express=require('express')
const router=express.Router()
const bcrypt=require('bcrypt')
const {Users,validateUsers}=require("../models/users_models")

router.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.cookie('jwtCookieget',"dummydataaasdasfahsfdf",{
    httpOnly:false,
    path:"/",
    maxAge:60*60*3*100000,
    secure: true,
    sameSite:'none',
    
})
    res.send("Get Router")
})
```

The path filed set to "/" is important without that your cookies might not get set under application tab. Please reach out if you need

Comment: By setting withCredential: true on the client side and credentials: true for the cors setting I was able to resolve the issue.